Azure devops pipeline failed on CopyFilesOverSSH task
I'm pretty much lost on why I'm getting an authentication error when trying to copy a file.

- task: SSH@0
  inputs:
    sshEndpoint: 'backend'
    runOptions: 'commands'
    commands: 'do something'
    readyTimeout: '20000'
  
- task: CopyFilesOverSSH@0
  inputs:
    sshEndpoint: 'backend'
    sourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    contents: 'api-core'
    targetFolder: '/opt/api'
    readyTimeout: '20000'

The SSH task works, but then I get an error on the CopyFilesOverSSH task:
Setting up SSH service connection to remote host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. ##[debug]task result: Failed ##[error]Error: Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. Failed to connect to remote machine.
I've used this exact same .yml on other projects and it's worked fine. I'm also able to sftp and ssh locally with my .pem

I have the same issue. I have tried to run the pipeline on both MS-hosted agent and self-hosted agent. SSH@0 works but CopyFilesOverSSH@0failed with the same error Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH service connection details. Error: All configured authentication methods failed .

I can ssh to the target Ubuntu VM using the public key on my self-hosted agent.
I can ping my target Ubuntu VM successfully on my self-hosted agent.

Finally, I resolve the issue by adding a 60-enable-rsa.conf file to sshd_config.d folder.

Run command cd .. /.. to see the etc directory
Under the path of /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d, enable sudo

cd /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d
sudo bash


Create the 60-enable-rsa.conf file with the command below

echo "
HostbasedAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
" >60-enable-rsa.conf


Restart sshd service

sudo systemctl restart sshd.service

Then CopyFilesOverSSH@0 works whether running on MS-hosted agent or self-hosted agent.

